# Docker container hits iptables to proxy

Tags: iptables, docker, proxy, nat, iproute

I have two VPSs, first machine (*proxy* from now) is for proxy and second machine (*dock* from now) is docker host. I want to redirect all traffic generated inside a docker container itself over *proxy*, to not exposure *dock* machines public IP.

As connection between VPSs is over internet, no local connection, created a tunnel between them by [ip tunnel](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-tunnel.8.html) as follows:

On *proxy*:

```
ip tunnel add tun10 mode ipip remote x.x.x.x local y.y.y.y dev eth0
ip addr add 192.168.10.1/24 peer 192.168.10.2 dev tun10
ip link set dev tun10 mtu 1492
ip link set dev tun10 up
```

On *dock*:

```
ip tunnel add tun10 mode ipip remote y.y.y.y local x.x.x.x dev eth0
ip addr add 192.168.10.2/24 peer 192.168.10.1 dev tun10
ip link set dev tun10 mtu 1492
ip link set dev tun10 up
```

PS: Do not know if *ip tunnel* can be used for production, it is another question, anyway planning to use [libreswan](https://libreswan.org/) or [openvpn](https://openvpn.net/) as a tunnel between VPSs.

After, added SNAT rules to iptables on both VPSs and some routing rules as follows:

On *proxy*:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.10.2/32 -j SNAT --to-source y.y.y.y
```

On *dock*:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 172.27.10.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.10.2
ip route add default via 192.168.10.1 dev tun10 table rt2
ip rule add from 192.168.10.2 table rt2
```

And last but not least created a docker network with one test container attached to it as follows:

```
docker network create --attachable --opt com.docker.network.bridge.name=br-test --opt com.docker.network.bridge.enable_ip_masquerade=false --subnet=172.27.10.0/24 testnet
docker run --network testnet alpine:latest /bin/sh
```

Unfortunately all these ended with no success. So the question is how to debug that? Is it correct way? How would you do the redirection over proxy?

Some words about theory: Traffic coming from 172.27.10.0/24 subnet hits iptables SNAT rule, source IP changes to 192.168.10.2. By routing rule it routes over tun10 device, it is the tunnel. And hits another iptables SNAT rule that changes IP to y.y.y.y and finally goes to destination.

Comment: To check inside container you can use: `apk add curl` `curl 'http://ipecho.net/plain'` It should return y.y.y.y

Answer (score 1):

> I want to redirect all traffic generated inside a docker container itself over proxy, to not exposure dock machines public IP.

If that is all you want, you don't need NAT between the two docker instances.

You do need to enable forwarding on the `proxy` instance (e.g. via sysctl).

If the public IP of `proxy` is **visible** inside `proxy`, then you need to do SNAT with that public IP inside `proxy` only (not in `dock`). This is also called MASQUERADE. It's a standard setup, google for "masquerade".

If the public IP of `proxy` is **not visible** inside `proxy` (i.e., listed when you do `ip addr`), because the host of `proxy` (or even some other host further up) does the NAT then you you should avoid double NAT and make `dock` appear just like another container to the host. Details depend on how the network is setup on the host (which you didn't say), but basically the tunnel end in `dock` will have to have an IP in the same subnet as the containers on the `proxy` host.

An `ipip` tunnel is not encrypted; you should not use this tunnel unless the transport is entirely inside a trusted network (which is probably not the case, because you seem to want different public IP addresses). So use `OpenVPN` or easy to setup alternatives like [tinc](https://www.tinc-vpn.org). `Libreswan` is not so easy to set up.

**Edit**

Step-by-step:

1) Verify the tunnel works. On `proxy`, do `ping 192.168.10.2`. On `dock`, do `ping 192.168.10.1`. Debug with `tcpdump` on all intervening network interfaces you have access to. If the ipip-tunnel doesn't work, use a different tunnel and make it work.

2) Remove all `iptables` rules on `dock`. Set the default route via the tunnel. Test with `ip route get 8.8.8.8` if the route works.

3) Assuming that `eth0` on `proxy` has the public IP, delete all `iptables` rules, do:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun10 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -o eth0 -i tun10 -j ACCEPT
```

This says "forward packets, masquerade all forwarded packets going out on `eth0` by giving them the public IP address on `eth0` as source address, and connection track them. Packets from `tun10` can always be forwarded to `eth0`, incoming packets on `eth0` only get forwarded to `tun10` if the connection was established by `dock`."

Test by doing `ping 8.8.8.8` on `dock`, while running `tcpdump` on `tun10` and `eth0` on `proxy`. You should see the packets forwarded, and the source being rewritten.

4) Once everything works, make it permanent: Edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` or a file in `/etc/sysctl.d` to have `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`. Either use a startup script to add the `iptables` rules, or use whatever package your distro provides to save the rules.

Comment: Thank you for reply. But as I see you did not understand correctly. There is no any docker instance in _proxy_, but docker instance is in _dock_ machine. The thing that I want to achieve is to redirect the traffic from docker instance over _proxy_ machine, not from _dock_ machine itself, so while accessing some resource from inside instance your public IP will be the _proxy_ public IP. Docker uses masquerading to provide connectivity out/in for its instances in a host.

Comment: It doesn't really matter if `proxy` and/or `dock` are docker instances or not If `proxy` is the host itself, the same applies: Is the public IP of `proxy` is visible in proxy (`ip addr`), or not (because your hosting service has other machines which do the NAT)? Depending on that, you either MASQUERADE only on `proxy`, or you pretend to whoever does the NAT that `dock` is just another machine, a peer of `proxy`, by forwarding/routing.

Comment: You say: `Details depend on how the network is setup on the host (which you didn't say)...` Is not this enough? `As connection between VPSs is over internet, no local connection,..`.

Comment: I cannot understand you. Can you please show me real working example. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I understood connection between VPSs is over the internet. This is not the point. Can you please look at the output of `ip addr` on `proxy`, and see if the public IP is listed there, or not? And if it is not listed, could you describe how `proxy` connects to whoever supplies the public IP? *That* is the point.

Comment: Both VPSs  have public IP assigned to their NIC. But, anyway, if `proxy` had not public IP assigned to its NIC, with masquerading the public IP would be, as you said, the suppliers public IP. However, I want, only for container, to change this IP to second VPSs public IP.

Comment: Yeah, at last. That is exactly what I want to do. But, one case you missed is that I do not want all traffic from `dock` to be routed over `proxy`, but ONLY AND ONLY specific docker subnet. So, thats why I cannot add default routing. Added it as a second table routing. While doing `ip route get` (thanks for clue) I figured out that my routing is not working, so digging further.